# Writing to serial port works via Putty but not PySerial

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am able to send a command string to the serial port via Putty and get a response. However, when I try the same using Python PySerial read/write I am not able to send read/write commands.

Putty terminal:
example-1:

```
 <command_string>
    response = Success
```

Example-2:

```
<incorrect_command_string>
response = Fail
```

Python code:

```
serialData = serial.Serial(port=2, baudrate=921600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                                   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
serialData.write(b'<command_string>')
print(serialData.in_waiting)
print(serialData.read(serialData.in_waiting))
```

Output of the code:

```
0  
b''
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I add  'sleep(1)' after the write it works. Is there a way around not using sleep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
The response string has '\r'. So I am able to use read_until as below and eliminate the sleep.

```
serialData.read_until("\r".encode('utf-8'))
```